# Counting unique values ​in columns of huge CSV files

Tags: python, csv, memory

My code reads a CSV file and counts the number of rows in it, the number of non-empty and unique values ​​in each column. It works well with small files, a few gigabytes in size. The problem arises with files larger than 20 gigabytes - each next million lines are processed more slowly and more slowly, and then a memory shortage occurs.

The problem is that the code processes unique values ​​in memory, which cannot be unlimited. Files can weigh not only 20 gigabytes, but also 200. How to solve this problem?

```
def read_csv(file_path, delimiter, encoding):


with open(file_path, encoding=encoding) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=delimiter)
    header = next(reader)
    columns = {col_name: {'total': 0, 'not_null': 0, 'unique': 0, 'first_five': set()} for col_name in header}
    column_data = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    print('!')
    num = 0
    for row in reader:
        if num % 1000000 == 0:  
            print(num / 1000000, 'M rows')
        num+=1

        try:
            for col_index, col_value in enumerate(row):
                column_name = header[col_index]

                columns[column_name]['total'] += 1
                if col_value:
                    columns[column_name]['not_null'] += 1
                    column_data[column_name][col_value] += 1
                    if column_data[column_name][col_value] == 1:
                        columns[column_name]['unique'] += 1
                        if len(columns[column_name]['first_five']) < 5:
                            columns[column_name]['first_five'].add(col_value)
        except:
            print(row)
```

Comment: Use `polars` with `streaming=True` to work on larger-than-memory files

Comment: Can you convert your data to a column value store like Arrow?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are counting unique values, you might have more wiggle room to hash the values prior to adding them to the dictionary/set. Maybe something like this:

```py
import csv
import hashlib
import json


with open("data.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file_in:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file_in)

    column_metadata = {
        col_name: {
            'total': 0,
            'not_null': 0,
            'unique': set(),
            'first_five': list()
        }
        for col_name in reader.fieldnames
    }

    for index, row in enumerate(reader):
        if index % 10_000 == 0:
            print(f"rows so far: {index}", end="\r", flush=True)

        for key, value in row.items():
            if value is None:
                continue

            metadata = column_metadata[key]
            metadata["not_null"] += 1
            metadata["unique"].add(hashlib.sha256(value.encode()))
            if index <= 4:
                metadata["first_five"].append(value)

for key, value in column_metadata.items():
    value["total"] = index
    value["unique"] = len(value["unique"])
print()
print(json.dumps(column_metadata, indent=4))
```

if you were concerned about a sha256 collision, I think hashlib will support a sha512 as well.